# Cant import a .csv file in outlook 2019

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

I try to export some of my gmail contact lists to outlook (2019). I can export the files in .csv format from gmail. However, I do not see a way to import .csv files in outlook.. When I tab file / import I only have .pst and .olm options.

Any thoughts on how I can import .csv files in this version of outlook (or another way to transfer contact lists?)

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-gmail-contacts-to-outlook-edbacfde-f48c-49da-a6a3-bcbb8f4f4819

Comment: Check if [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-contacts-to-outlook-bb796340-b58a-46c1-90c7-b549b8f3c5f8) helps.

Comment: Outlook for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Importing of Excel or CSV file into Outlook for Mac isn't supported. For suggested workarounds, visit [Answers.Microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac/mac-outlook-2016-import-contacts/7f944d99-1f56-4a7b-808f-e845e908cc08).

Answer (score 0):

You can import your contact list from .csv format into Outlook.
For this just follow these steps.

1. Select the File option in the top left corner.
2. Now, choose Open & Export and then Import/Export.
3. After that select the option Import from another program or file, and click on Next.
4. Select Comma Separated value and then click on Next.
5. In the File to Import box, browse to your contact file and select by double click on it.
6. Select the option from

   1. Replace Duplicates with items imported.
   2. Allow duplicates to be created.
   3. Do not import duplicate items.
7. Then click on Next and select the Destination folder.
8. Click on Finish. Now, Outlook begins importing your contacts immediately.
9. Choose the People Icon from the bottom to see your Contacts.

I hope this will help you to import your Google Contacts into Outlook.